# How do I make a command loop a certain number of times before making it end the command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

With the following code, I would like to make it loop 2 times before ending, to prevent spam in chat.

```
while answer.lower() != "proceed" and answer.lower() != "return":
    await ctx.send("Only enter 'proceed' or 'return'!")
    await ctx.send('''Are you sure you want to nuke this channel? This will completely erase all messages from it!
type proceed to continue, and return to return. ''')
    answer = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda
        message: message.author == ctx.author and message != "")  # Gets user input and checks if message is not empty and was sent by the same user
    answer = answer.content
```

I would like to do it with this code-

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

```py
# use a counter to track how many times you run the while loop
loop_counter = 0
while answer.lower() != "proceed" and answer.lower() != "return": 
    loop_counter += 1
    if loop_counter >=2:
    # break out of the loop if reach a threshold.
    # send out the message before break out of the loop.
        await ctx.send("The loop has ended.") 
        break
    await ctx.send("Only enter 'proceed' or 'return'!") 
    await ctx.send('''Are you sure you want to nuke this channel? This will completely erase all messages from it! type proceed to continue, and return to return. ''') 
    answer = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message != "") 
     # Gets user input and checks if message is not empty and was sent by the same user answer = answer.content
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked-- And how would I add a message to state that the loop had ended?

Comment: @Benjamin Check the update, you can send a message before break the loop.